# How to ensure that an iOS device is secure

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security, uuid

Is there any way for an app to verify that an iDevice is password protected? If not, is there any way to ensure that an app can only install/run on a "protected" list of devices? UUID is now depreciated, but do any alternatives exist? Are there any free device management programs?

Comment: If you aren't submitting it to the appstore why don't you just access the UDID anyway? Alternatively you can use the mac address.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to infer that a passcode is set: querying the protecteddataAvailable property on the UIApplication object.

Without using an MDM solution to manage device and install apps through, I don't think there is a way to prevent your app being installed on an unsecured device. And then even so, the user could just install by hand. What you could do in our app is to test at launch whether there's a passcode and if not inform the user.

Comment: Wouldn't that return YES if there is no password set? The documentation isn't very clear on this.